# What is OpenIPMI and how to use it?

Tags: linux, ipmi

I was found in Ubuntu repo package with name openipmi, what is it and how to use this package? It's IPMI Emulator or what? and how to connect to OpenIPMI?

Comment: OpenIPMI is deprecated. It's no longer maintained. Use [FreeIPMI](https://www.gnu.org/software/freeipmi/). It's more open-source, more easier and more features. Most of all, it's still maintained.

Comment: OpenIPMI has code commits on its sourceforge git repository as recently as March 29, 2023. https://sourceforge.net/p/openipmi/code/ci/master/tree/

Answer (score 0):

According to the `OpenIMPI` project webpage (http://openipmi.sourceforge.net/), OpenIMPI is not an emulator but is

> ... an effort to create a full-function IPMI system to allow full access to all IPMI information on a server and to abstract it to a level that will make it easy to use.

You can connect to `OpenIMPI` in a number of ways, including using the `ipmicmd` program which lets you inject and receive messages.